# Is the Kotlin term "mutable" wrong?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, variables, constants

The way I understood things is that the word "variable" referred to the capability of a reference to be reassigned. "constant" meant a reference cannot be reassigned. Essentially the difference between final or not in Java.

```
var something = new obj() -> reference can be re-assigned  
val something = new obj() -> cannot be re-assigned
```

To me "mutability" meant the ability to modify the REFERAND/OBJECT itself, not its reference. I.E. the object *being* referenced. But Kotlin doesn't prevent that.

You can have

```
val something = new obj()
```

but still be able to "mutate" that obj() without reassigning to a new identifier.

Am I misunderstanding something, or is this a misnomer?

Comment: In Java, "constant" often refers to `static final`, not just `final`. Regardless, when Kotlin says `var` is mutable it means it can be reassigned (i.e. non-final). So the reference is mutable, separate from the mutability of the object being referenced.

Comment: Java also uses the term variable for immutable references. They’re called “immutable variables” even though that’s semantically an oxymoron. In Kotlin, “constant” is a specific kind of `val` declared in an object or at the top level, places where `val` would normally be a property rather than a variable without the `const` keyword.

Comment: You're on to something...kotlin really got constants wrong.  And they keep making changes to try to make it less onerous.  Many languages have done variables and constants right--too bad the makers of kotlin didn't do their homework on other languages (they were just reacting to their own dislike of java).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`val`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-syntax.html#variables) and [`var`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/basic-syntax.html#variables) only control the immutability of the reference not the object that it points to.

From [Kotlin in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/kotlin-in-action)

> There are two keywords to declare a variable:
>
> 1. `val` (from value)—Immutable reference. A variable declared with `val` can’t be reassigned after it’s initialized. It corresponds to a `final`
>    variable in Java.
> 2. `var` (from variable)—Mutable reference. The value of such a variable can be changed. This declaration corresponds to a regular
>    (non-final) Java variable.
>
> ***Note that, even though a `val` reference is itself immutable and can’t***
> ***be changed, the object that it points to may be mutable***. For example,
> this code is perfectly valid:
>
> ```
> val languages = arrayListOf("Java")
> languages.add("Kotlin")
> ```

Comment: Yes, but is this moving away from the traditional concept of what "immutable" referred to? Usually, it was about the object being referenced. What would you call an object that is not mutable then?

Comment: @heapoverflow The documents specify that this is an immutable _reference_.

Comment: Don't get confused, immutable means _unable to be changed._ both references and the referenced objects can have this property.

Comment: An immutable class is one whose stateful properties are all  immutable. It really is the same word meaning the same thing.